# className in destructured prop doesn't apply to component sometimes, is it a bug? (Next.JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component as such:

```js
import classNames from "classnames";

const Button = (props) => {
  const { className, children, ...rest } = props;
  const [internalProps, setInternalProps] = useState(rest);
  const [classes, setClasses] = useState("");

  const validateProps = () => {
    const tmp: Props = Object.assign(rest, {});
    const classes = [
      "btn",
      className,
      { "btn-block": block },
      { "btn-sm": size === "sm" },
      { "btn-lg": size === "lg" },
    ];

    setClasses(classNames(classes));
    setInternalProps(tmp);
  };

  useEffect(validateProps, [props]);

  return (
    <button className={classes} {...internalProps}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

The `className` prop is taken out of `internalProps` because for whatever reason, when included in it, the classes aren't applied sometimes when the page is loaded. I have no idea why this is happening, AFAIK `className` is treated as just another prop in React. I am still new to React and Next.JS though, so I may be missing something basic here. Has anyone experienced something like this?

Comment: Why are you using `useState` and `useEffect` here? Simply having `className={classNames(classes)}` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `internalProps` to be the same as `rest`, and `rest` doesn't include `className`.

This line:

```
const { className, children, ...rest } = props
```

means:
From the `props` take `className` and `children`, and put all the *remaining* properties *(not including `className` and `children`)* into `rest`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that even if I set `tmp.className = classNames(classes)` in `validateProps()`, React would still not recognize the class names. I thought `internalProps` would be set with `validateProps` via `useEffect` and thus include the class names, but it doesn't appear to be so.